# Error in service call using Google Api discovery service

Tags: ios

I m getting following in service call

"Optional(Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=404 \"(Not Found)\" UserInfo={error=Not Found, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Not Found), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x600000655870: {message:\"Not Found\" data:[1] code:404}})"

what could be the reason ?

classes are as follows

```
@implementation GTLServiceMovier
- (instancetype)init {
   self = [super init];
    if (self) {
   // Version from discovery.
     self.apiVersion = @"v2";
   self.rpcURL = [NSURL URLWithString:SERVER_URL]
}
  return self;
}

@end


+ (instancetype)queryForSmartMovieWithObject:(GTLSmartMovieEndApiModelResult *)object {
if (object == nil) {
    GTL_DEBUG_ASSERT(object != nil, @"%@ got a nil object", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return nil;
}
NSString *methodName = @"mvi.get.movies.start";
SmartMovieQuery *query = [self queryWithMethodName:methodName];
query.bodyObject = object;
query.expectedObjectClass = [GTLSmartMovieEndApiModelResult class];
return query;
```

}

Comment: Since the error response returns a 404, you should check if you've got the url right. Just paste the final url in a browser and see if you get the desired response.